# Mootools callback function not processed

Tags: javascript, mootools

So I have this piece of code which just won't work. I'm trying to trigger an event when the audio has finished playing.

```
item.addEventListener("ended", function () {
  slides.show("next", function () {
    alert("TESTING!");
  });
});
```

The slide changes but the alert is never thrown.

The code below works, but then the alert will fire before the the next slide event is finished.

```
item.addEventListener("ended", function () {
  slides.show("next");
  alert("TESTING!");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `slides` is an [`Fx.Slide`](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Slide#Fx-Slide) (although it seems odd that it's a plural), [according to the docs](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Slide#Fx-Slide%3ashow) there is no callback on `show`.

And that makes sense. Since the `show` occurs with no transition/animation, there's no need for a callback. Just put the next thing you want to happen after the call to `show` (as shown in your second code block).

Comment: slides is actually a slideshow. However, It seems I've been using jQuery so long that I actually forgot that not every function has a callback :)